# GolangCI Not Removing Unused Imports

Tags: go, golint, golangci-lint, goimports

For some reason my GolangCI is able to identify unused imports but not able to remove them. This is my GolangCI file used to remove unused import statements, I did specify remove-unused as true:

```
run:
  timeout: 5m
  modules-download-mode: mod

linters:
  enable:
    - errcheck
    - goimports
    - revive
    - govet
    - staticcheck

linters-settings:
  goimports:
    remove-unused: true

  misspell:
    locale: US

issues:
  exclude-use-default: false
  max-issues-per-linter: 0
  max-same-issues: 0
```

This is how I am running my golangCI:

```
lint-build-code: ## Lint the generated Code in the Build Folder
    @echo "Linting code in directory: $(GEN_CODE_DIR)/src"
    docker run --rm -v $(PWD):/local \
        -w /local golangci/golangci-lint:latest \
        golangci-lint run --fix --config $(GOLANG_CI) --verbose ./$(GEN_CODE_DIR)/src/**
```

Answer (score 0):

I wish I could have gotten GolangCI to work but I couldn't. This is what I used to get the job done, if anyone has a way to get GolangCI work let me know.

```
remove-unused-imports: generate-code ## Remove unused imports
    @echo "Removing unused imports"
    cd ./$(GEN_CODE_DIR)/src/ && docker run --rm -v $(PWD):/data cytopia/goimports -d -w .
```